# confusion in use of filters in ec2 and boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to print the public DNS name of my instance

so I wrote a code here

```
import sys
import boto3


instance_id = "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
action = 'ON'

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

if action == 'ON':
   response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
else:
    response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
print(response)

resp=ec2.describe_network_interfaces();
print ("printing pub dns name")
print(resp['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName'])



def get_name(inst):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
    foo = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName']
    return foo


foo = get_name(instance_id)
print (foo)
```

The error I get is in lines

```
response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
```

in get_name

```
    response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'instance_id'
```

How do I use a filter here?

Comment: You pass `instance_id` as `inst`, and it is a string, so `inst[0]` is still a string of length 1.

Comment: I am not able to understand can you elaborate more.

Comment: First you have `instance_id = "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"`, then later `get_name(instance_id)`.

Comment: ok that is the problem.`response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [instance_id])` fixes the problem.Thanks,by the way I want to know what does inst[0] contains, I am new to python and still learning it